# setInterval not updating html element

Tags: javascript

Basically I'm trying to have my code update the value of an element every second.  Problem is my current code only updates it the first time. No errors in console either.

The weird part is that the console.log() keeps running after but the element doesn't update and neither does the time variable

```js
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var date = today.getFullYear() + '/' + String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '/' + String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');

setInterval(function() {
  time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var elTime = document.getElementById("time");
  elTime.textContent = time;
  console.log(time);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: please paste the entire code to help with the issue

Comment: where is `today` declared? (original code before edit) - your code as shown produces errors and never runs - if adding `var today = new Date;` before the `time =` like, then your code works just fine

Comment: Yeah I updated the code sorry

Comment: since today is set once, why would it ever change? `var today = new Date();` needs to be the first line in the callback

Comment: Oh do I have to update the value of today as well?

Comment: @KA - yes, of course

Comment: Like @NidhinJoseph said, could you please post the HTML as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, the variables also need to be updated each time the `setInterval` is executed.

```js
(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '/' + String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '/' + String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    var elTime = document.getElementById("time");
    elTime.textContent = time;
    console.log(time);
  }, 1000);
})()
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-set "Today" for every tick of the interval. Change to this:

```
setInterval(function(){
   var heute= new Date();
  time = heute.getHours() + ":" + heute.getMinutes() + ":" + heute.getSeconds();
  var elTime = document.getElementById("time");
  elTime.textContent = time;
  console.log(time);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to add a description of why this works and why the original option doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A simple working `setInterval` program looks like the following.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  var elTime = document.getElementById("time");
  elTime.textContent = parseInt(elTime.textContent) + 1;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time">0</div>
```

Notice all the code that needs execute is inside the scope of the `setInterval` function. To fix your problem, add all code inside the scope of the function so it runs every single time like so.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  //Variables
  var today = new Date();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var date = today.getFullYear() + '/' + String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '/' + String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var elTime = document.getElementById("time");
  elTime.textContent = time;
  console.log(time);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`SetInterval` is a function call system.

for information: `SetInterval` can not serve as a precise clock, the durrée between each apple is an indication for the interpreter, and depending on the tasks it must perform elsewhere, it can return beyond the requested period, which is usually the case. For a request of 1000ms, it can realize the call after 1004ms, 1020ms, or even more.

and more easy to use native JS time formating => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

```js
const elTime = document.getElementById("time")

ShowTime()                    // first attempt
setInterval(ShowTime, 1000)  //  next ones

function ShowTime()
{
  let t_Now = new Date()
  elTime.textContent = t_Now.toLocaleTimeString('default', { hour12:false } ) 
}
```

```html
<p id="time"></p>
```